# Excel Power Query - split table by sheets using criteria

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm new in Power Query so I need some help. I have a simple table in my XLS file which is placed to Datasheet. I'm using `=Excel.CurrentWorkbook()` command to load table from same workbook cause I have my datasource in the same workbook. So this command can load a slightly modified table to another list I can delete columns or change their order etc. But my goal is to use criteria and split source data table using value in Customer column to different sheets. I mean rows which contains Key1 keyword should be loaded to "Key1 Sheet" and rows which contains Key2 to "Key2 Sheet"
I don't need to create sheets dynamically cause I have only 3 keys so I can prepare sheets by myself. But which query should I use to select rows of the source table by keyword and load it to defined sheet?

My table looks like this

```
Date            Customer    Product                     Sold By Value
09.01.2019 0:00  Key1        Farmhouse Bloomer  Sally   76
02.01.2019 0:00  Key1        Tiger  Sally               40
19.01.2019 0:00  Key1        Gluten Free Sally          66
19.01.2019 0:00  Key1        Tiger  David               51
12.01.2019 0:00  Key1        Farmhouse Bloomer  David   75
22.01.2019 0:00  Key1        Farmhouse Bloomer  Mark    46
23.01.2019 0:00  Key2        Tiger  Lucy                40
25.01.2019 0:00  Key2        White Sliced   David       57
23.01.2019 0:00  Key2        White Sliced   John        50
10.01.2019 0:00  Key2        White Sliced   Sally       75
06.01.2019 0:00  Key2        Tiger  Lucy                49
10.01.2019 0:00  Key2        White Sliced   David       60
11.01.2019 0:00  Key2        Gluten Free    Lucy        38
31.01.2019 0:00  Key2        Farmhouse Bloomer  Lucy    43
06.01.2019 0:00  Key2        Tiger  John                45
18.01.2019 0:00  Key3        Tiger  Sally               64
20.01.2019 0:00  Key3        Brown Sliced   John        57
05.01.2019 0:00  Key3        Tiger  David               38
29.01.2019 0:00  Key3        Brown Sliced   Lucy        49
13.01.2019 0:00  Key3        Brown Sliced   David       73
```

Comment: You'll need three separate queries and just filter each one on the relevant column, and load each to a separate sheet.

Comment: Yes i understand but im quite new in PQ. It would be great to have some example of selecting by value

Comment: Click the filter dropdown at the top of the relevant column, and select the value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rory mentionned in the comments section, you can create three different queries and load them in three separate sheets.

[image]

Here is how looks like one of the three queries (assuming that your original dataset is formatted in a table named `MyTable`:

```
let
    Source = MyTable,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Customer] = "Key1"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

`Source = MyTable` in the first line means that the `Key1_sheet` is just a reference of the query `MyTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

1. select your entire table in the Excel sheet
2. Go to Data>From Table/Range. This will open PQ. Now you see your first query at the left panel.
3. Duplicate it twice, using right-click mouse on it in that panel.
4. Give each of the three queries a name, say, Key1_Sheet, Key2_Sheet, Key3_Sheet, as @L'Artiste suggested.
5. Click on the name of the first one to open it in the central panel (the Data Grid Panel) then
6. click on some 'Key1' text line. Then
7. right-click with mouse and choose the 'Equals' text filter.
8. Do the same on the other queries, obviously changing each filter to 'Key2' and 'Key3'.

You're done with PQ.

9. Choose 'Close and Load' (Home tab).
10. On the Excel front-end open the 'Queries and Connections' panel (Data>Queries and Connections) and you'll see them listed there. Right-click one at a time and choose "Load to..." and configure each one to the desired sheet.